# Storing Website-wide variables

Tags: variables, web

Used to developing but nothing web based, and all the questions I find require client based data like cookies/session data.

I want to know how and where can I store data for my website that everyone would access? What are all my options and what are the pros/cons of each.

I basically need like 8 URLs on the homepage which will vary based on a simple bool that will be changed on each page behind the URL, how might I manage that? The change on the 2nd page will influence the first page for everyone hence needing to avoid client data

Comment: Both cookies and session data are unique to an individual visitor. You would need a server-side programming language and probably also a database. As for toggling different displays of hyperlinks, that would be done with a simple `if` conditional.

Comment: For 8 URLs? How can that be done viably? What's the best way to set it up? Anything basic that points me in a direction will help (especially if it's ELI5 in style)

Comment: It depends entirely on the language used, but you would simply do something like store 8 different flags in the database (which get updated by page 2), connect to the database on page 1, then output the flag data with something like (in PHP & MySQLi as an example): `if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "<a href='$row[link]'>$row[link]</a>"; }}`.